# Subset data using information from a different data frame [r]

Tags: r

I have two data frames.  One contains a large amount of data.  The second contains a smaller amount of data with some matching row names.

```
data frame A
Row.names  data
    1       A
    2       B
    3       C
    4       D
    5       E

data frame B
Row.names  data
    1       X
    3       Y
    5       Z
```

I want to extract the data from data frame A using the row.names from data frame B to create:

```
data frame C
Row.names   data
    1        A
    3        C
    5        E
```

I basically want to use to row names from data frame B to subset data from data frame A that has the exact same row names.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `A[rownames(B),]` ??  (I am assuming that you are really referring to row names, not to columns called "Row.names")

Comment: Ben is correct...using *real* row names is the way to go here. Plus an optional `, drop=F` if the data frame is only one column and you want to keep it that way.