# Subsetting based on values of a different data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to subset data if every value in the row is greater than the respective row in a different data frame. I also need to skip some top rows. These previous questions did not help me, but it is related:

[Subsetting a data frame based on contents of another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452205/subsetting-a-data-frame-based-on-contents-of-another-data-frame)

[Subset data using information from a different data frame [r]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191026/subset-data-using-information-from-a-different-data-frame-r)

```
> A
     name1 name2
cond   trt  ctrl
hour     0     3
A        1     1
B       10     1
C        1     1
D        1     1
E       10    10
> B
     name1 name2
cond   trt  ctrl
hour     0     3
A        1     1
B        1    10
C        1     1
D        1     1
E        1     1
```

I want this. Only rows where ALL values were greater in A than B:

```
     name1 name2
cond   trt  ctrl
hour     0     3
E       10    10
```

I've tried these 3 lines:

```
subset(A, TRUE, select=(A[3:7,] > B[3:7,]))
subset(A, A > B)
A[A[3:7,] > B[3:7,]]
```

Thanks so much. Here is the code to generate the data:

```
A <- structure(list(name1 = c("trt", "0", "1", "10", "1", "1", "10"
), name2 = c("ctrl", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "10")), .Names = c("name1", 
"name2"), row.names = c("cond", "hour", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
), class = "data.frame")
B <- structure(list(name1 = c("trt", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), 
    name2 = c("ctrl", "3", "1", "10", "1", "1", "1")), .Names = c("name1", 
"name2"), row.names = c("cond", "hour", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
), class = "data.frame")
```

############# Follow-up question asked 2/28/13

[Error when subsetting based on adjusted values of different data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147336/error-when-subsetting-based-on-adjusted-values-of-different-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: the 'hours' row values are NOT greater than.  Do you want to ignore that row?

Comment: Yes I want to ignore the hour and cond categories

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
N <- nrow(A)
cond <- sapply(3:N, function(i) sum(A[i,] > B[i,])==2)
rbind(A[1:2,], subset(A[3:N,], cond))
```

Comment: This is very good. I see that you're including a function to apply to those values. But I am confused about the i? Does sapply use a loop or something? What I really like about this is I can now change sum==2 to 1 if I want 50% of values in A are greater than B.

Comment: Note side : The use of sum is good , but it is a little bit trick.  What if you have a condition like A.name1 **>** A.name2 and A.name1 **<** B.name2?

Comment: Very true agstudy. That is actually where I plan on going with this. Speed seems alright, redmode's took 20 seconds with my real data set. But you're right about a problem when adding more logic.

Comment: when I do something like `sum(A[i,] > 0.95*B[i,])==2` , I get an error  `Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. How can I do this to have the values in A greater than 95% of B?

Comment: @chimpsarehungry: `sapply` is _loop-like_ operator, it passes values from `3` to `N` to anonymous function which returns one logical value. All returned values are combined in array. `i` is formal argument of anonymous function, every time it holds the value (from `3` to `N`) passed to the function.

Comment: @chimpsarehungry: As far as first rows of your `data.frame` hold `character` values, all data in `A` and `B` are treated like characters. Perhaps, you are looking for `sum(as.numeric(A[i,]) > 0.95*as.numeric(B[i,]))==2`

Answer (score 3):

I think it is better to use SQL for such inter table filtering. It is clean and readable( You keep the rules logic).

```
 library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT DISTINCT A.*
        FROM A,B
        WHERE A.name1   > B.name1
        AND    A.name2  > B.name2')
  name1 name2
1   trt  ctrl
2    10    10
```

Comment: "Clean and readable"?  What kind of software jock are you anyway?  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft sorry for my English. I mean by clean that this solution don't hide the origin condition like using sum or prod in the 2 others solutions. I think also that is faster than sapply(maybe slower than data.table solution which has the same logic). Anyway, I am a .net programmer how try to learn R theses days.( i am not sure to understand very well "software jock").

Comment: He's just joking, saying you're solution is too human-readable. I like it though. I will have to get that library.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft oups !Thanks. I can't learn R and "English second level joke" on the same time :)

Comment: @agstudy no offense taken.  In fact, I think you've inspired me to take a look at `sqldf`

Answer (score 3):

requisite data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)

# just to preserve the order, non-alphabetically
idsA <- factor(rownames(A), levels=rownames(A))
idsB <- factor(rownames(B), levels=rownames(B))

# convert to data.table with id
ADT <- data.table(id=idsA, A, key="id")
BDT <- data.table(id=idsB, B, key="id")

# filter as needed
ADT[BDT][name1 > name1.1 & name2 > name2.1, list(id, name1, name2)]
```

Comment: I love when I get such a variety of solutions. Thanks Ricardo

Comment: Is there a way to make that filtering part not rely on having the names of the columns. Just filter based on respective location of columns in A and B.

Comment: Yep, you can do filter as you would a data.frame, but at the end, add `, with=FALSE]`

Answer (score 2):

If I rename your matrices `amat` and `bmat`, then

```
amat[which(sapply(1:nrows(amat),function(x) prod(amat[x,]>bmat[x,]))==1),]
[1] 10 10
```

And you can paste the 'hours' row back on if desired.

Comment: Which is basically the same thing @redmode did, So I consider myself ninja'd in time but not in obfuscation.

Comment: You lost my alphabet Carl.