# Subsetting a repetitive indexed dataframe using values from a non-repetitive but similarly indexed smaller dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

To begin with I already went through these

- [Subsetting a data frame based on contents of another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452205/subsetting-a-data-frame-based-on-contents-of-another-data-frame)
- [Subsetting based on values of a different data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097497/subsetting-based-on-values-of-a-different-data-frame-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but, I couldn't find a solution. I have two dataframes

```
big<- data.frame(ID=rep(1:10,each=6),V= seq(1,30,1.5))

small<- data.frame(ID=1:10,Vmean= c(8.0,15,23.1,2.2,1,2.1,10,7,14,21))
```

You would notice that the ID is the same in both dfs but, in df big it repeats and each repeated row has a different V.

What I want to achieve is:

using the ID from df small and corresponding Vmean, I want to subset and remove the rows of df big which are of similar ID but where value of V is greater than the corresponding Vmean values from df small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method in base R using `merge` and `with`.

```
big[with(merge(big, small, by="ID"), V <= Vmean),]
```

Merge the data.frames on ID. Use this object inside of `with` to perform a logical comparison of V and Vmean variables. The output of `with` will be a logical vector that you can use to subset the data.frame named big.

This returns

```
   ID    V
1   1  1.0
2   1  2.5
3   1  4.0
4   1  5.5
5   1  7.0
7   2 10.0
8   2 11.5
9   2 13.0
10  2 14.5
13  3 19.0
14  3 20.5
15  3 22.0
21  4  1.0
41  7  1.0
42  7  2.5
43  8  4.0
44  8  5.5
45  8  7.0
49  9 13.0
```

Note that this assumes that ID is unique in the small data.frame and that the small data.frame contains all of the IDs that big contains. Also, it assumes that big is sorted by ID.

A bit more robust would be to perform the operation in two steps

```
datNew <- merge(big, small, by="ID", all.x=TRUE)
datNew <- datNew[V <= Vmean | is.na(Vmean)),]
```

Comment: But I think they want to drop rows where V is greater.

Comment: Right, so this keeps rows where V is less then Vmean and drops rows where V is greater than Vmean.

Comment: I had to read it more than once initially and again with your comment to re-verify.